# Forces On Comets

Tags: astronomy, space, comets

This is the orbit of a comet
[image]

The question is -
Draw an arrow at point D to show the direction of the force acting on the comet.

At point D, the comet is moving away from the Sun, so i think that the force arrow pointing away from the Sun

But the answer is the opposite. It's pointing towards the Sun. Is it because of gravity? Why is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force on the comet *always* points towards the Sun, the velocity could point the opposite direction and there would be no contradiction. Imagine this: standing on the surface of the earth the force on you is towards the center of the earth. If you jump up, at some point you're moving up, and the force you experience is still pulling you down, towards the center of the Earth

Comment: could you explain this is more detail? is it the force of gravity?

Comment: What else would it be? Gravity is the only force acting on the comet in this scenario (which is ignoring negligible things like solar radiation pressure)

Comment: @RishiMalhotra Correct, it is gravity

Comment: Ok I get that but the fact the comet is moving away from the Sun, so doesn't that mean that a force is pushing it forwards too.

Comment: @RishiMalhotra No, it moves because of inertia. Same as when you're in a car, and hit the breaks: car keeps moving, but there's no force pushing forward